# Volley JsonObjectRequest Post request ignoring params

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to connect to an API using volley, I'm setting all the parameters and headers, but it seems that the params are being ignored, what am I missing here? I started learning android volley last week and I'm kind of lost.

```
    package com.rep.app.principal;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.rep.R;


    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import java.util.Map;


    public class InicioActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


       RequestQueue queue = null;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

            queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


            AutenticacaoLocalTask mAutenticacaoLocalTask = new AutenticacaoLocalTask();
            mAutenticacaoLocalTask.execute((Void) null);

        }
        private TextView txtDisplay;



        public class AutenticacaoLocalTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


                try {


                    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

                    String url = "http://192.168.1.18/opa/api/";


                   JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                System.out.println(response);

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        })

                   {

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkDaaDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");

                        return headers;
                    }

   @Override 
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", "rm@test.com.br");
                    params.put("senha", "aaa");

                    return params;
                }
          };    

              queue.add(jsObjRequest);
                    return true;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("RM", e.getMessage());
                    return false;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: It seem you are asking two duplicate questions, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285544/android-volley-http-request-custom-header) is your previous question and you accepted an answer, why you still ask this?

Answer (score 3):

It is obvious that sometimes we need to submit request parameters while hitting the url. To do that we have to override `getParams()` method which should return list of parameters to be send in a key value format.

So,Override `getParams()` in `JsonObjectRequest`  as

```
            @Override 
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", "rm@test.com.br");
                params.put("senha", "aaa");

                return params;
            }
```

i.e. use below code as

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                System.out.println(response);

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        })

                   {

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2C40Gm2lFJ2J0G9JkDaaDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");

                        return headers;
                    }

   @Override 
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", "rm@test.com.br");
                    params.put("senha", "aaa");

                    return params;
                }
          };
```

For more info see [Android working with Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

**EDIT:**

**401** is the status code for "unauthorized". If you are getting a **401** while trying an HTACCESS see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android). You need to pass the parameters using an `Authenticator`.

Comment: still getting error 401, If I remove the password and the email from the server and leave only the token as security it works perfectly

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting params along a request, try with the third parameter of the `JsonObjectRequest` object, which is a JSON object (`jsonobj` in my code).

Something like:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        System.out.println("onResponse()");

        ...
    }
});
```

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491561/5082708).