# JsonObjectRequest returns 415

Tags: android, json, jsonobjectrequest

I have a server in tomcat and I am trying to make a request from my android device. All I get back is 415. I havent been able to replicate the error with fiddler by sending a defective Json. The server does not react to my request. I do have println() at every step just in case.

```
                   try {
                        params.put("userId", 2);
                        params.put("latitude", lon1);
                        params.put("longitude", lat1);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    errTextBox.setText(params.toString());

                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            url, params.toString(),
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    msg.setText(response.toString());

                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            msg.setText("not ok " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }) {

                        /**
                         * Passing some request headers
                         * */
                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                            return headers;
                        }

                    };
                    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                    queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

Not a dublicate because my request is done with a JsonObjectRequest. Also removing the charset did not help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json)

Comment: it does the same thing without those lines. I did try it on different machines on local host/over the internet with the same result. 415 on android, success(200) on fiddler

Comment: Pls post screenshot of fiddler or postman

Comment: edited post to include requested screen shot

Comment: `lon1` and `lat1`, are they `string`?

Comment: Try using `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");` (without `charset=utf-8`) or `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");` (no space between `application/json` and `charset=utf-8`)

Comment: yes they are. Also I am using API 19 (kitkat/4.4.2) if that helps

Comment: does not work. I did an exact c/p. Also did try every combination before

Comment: Checkout this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575070/2308683

Comment: the same. with and without charset. On api 19 and 23 on emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I may have made a boo boo.
In my server software I was already parsing the recived string to Json.
So the is that I needed to send plain text...

```
@Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf8");
                            return headers;
```