# Volley not sending variable to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

i am trying to get volley to work with a php script, to basically submit some data via volley to the php then select from database and return result, however i am struggling to even get the variables from android to submit to the php. The errors i am getting signal that the variables are null when the php is run, so they are not getting submitted properly
Here is the php error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name
```

And when i try to return the variable `name` it returns as `null`

Here is the php

```
$iName = $_POST['name'];
$iEmail = $_POST['email'];
$iPassword = $_POST['password'];
$iVerifyPassword = $_POST['verify_password'];


$response = array('code' => "1", 'message' => $iName);

echo json_encode($response);

exit;
```

Here is the relevant android

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("name", sName);
params.put("email", sEmail);
params.put("password", sPassword);
params.put("verify_password", sVerifyPassword);

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(
    jsonUrl, new JSONObject(params),
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                int code = response.getInt("code");
                String message = response.getString("message");

                if (code == 1) {
                    //Success go to verify
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (code == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Network Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    }
);

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JsonObjectRequest` won't submit your parameters to the server, which cause your problem. This sort of questions has been asked by many guys, my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24402403/1294681) can make you more clear about why.

Comment: Ok that looks great, i am going to give that a try, just out of curiosity do i set the params with hashmap and pass them into the custom request or do i just add them to a jsonobject. Also where do i conduct all the onResponse code? Thanks for the help

Comment: you can trace the source code, then you can figure out that how the `JsonRequest` dealing with your parameters **HashMap**, its code were not large so quite easy to understand.

Comment: ok cool, i got there in the end, when i added the code from the link you gave me, it allowed me to create the onresponse methods, and the hashmap worked great. so thanks again