# How to send a POST request using volley with string body?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, android-volley

I'm developing an Android app that communicate with a RESTful web service I wrote. Using `Volley` for `GET` methods is awesome and easy, but I can't put my finger on the `POST` methods.

I want to send a `POST` request with a `String` in the body of the request, and retrieve the raw response of the web service (like `200 ok`, `500 server error`).

All I could find is the `StringRequest` which doesn't allow to send with data (body), and also it bounds me to receive a parsed `String` response.
I also came across `JsonObjectRequest` which accepts data (body) but retrieve a parsed `JSONObject` response.

I decided to write my own implementation, but I cannot find a way to receive the raw response from the web service. How can I do it?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can refer to the following code (of course you can customize to get more details of the network response):

```
try {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL = "http://...";
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("Title", "Android Volley Demo");
    jsonBody.put("Author", "BNK");
    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                // can get more details such as response.headers
            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Its worked but had to remove bodyContentType and parseNetworkResponse methods

Comment: @kondal, `parseNetworkResponse ` is used for the OP's requirement (`and retrieve the raw response of the web service`)

Comment: @user31231234124 yes, as I commented above, it's for the second requirement of the OP :)

Comment: @BNK if there is image file(in my request body) how to send it? pls tell

Comment: @ShikharJaiwal pls refer to an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity

Comment: To access the POSTed data in a PHP script, you could use: `$raw_data = file_get_contents("php://input"); $json_data = json_decode($raw_data); $title = $json_data->Title; $author = $json_data->Author;`

Comment: @BNK could you please have a look at this similar question of mine? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014420/not-able-to-post-jsonobject-in-the-body-using-volley-stringrequest

Comment: .. And How to do this job via Kotlin?

Answer (score 18):

I liked [this](https://gist.github.com/mombrea/7250835) one, but it is `sending JSON not string` as requested in the question, reposting the code here, in case the original github got removed or changed, and this one found to be useful by someone.

```
public static void postNewComment(Context context,final UserAccount userAccount,final String comment,final int blogId,final int postId){
    mPostCommentResponse.requestStarted();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://api.someservice.com/post/comment", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            mPostCommentResponse.requestCompleted();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mPostCommentResponse.requestEndedWithError(error);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user",userAccount.getUsername());
            params.put("pass",userAccount.getPassword());
            params.put("comment", Uri.encode(comment));
            params.put("comment_post_ID",String.valueOf(postId));
            params.put("blogId",String.valueOf(blogId));

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
}

public interface PostCommentResponseListener {
    public void requestStarted();
    public void requestCompleted();
    public void requestEndedWithError(VolleyError error);
}
```

Comment: what is "mPostCommentResponse"?

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty ```mPostCommentResponse``` its the custom callback for throwing the response back to the activity or fragment.

Comment: If it's sending json, why does it have set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: I saw a video about this code . I suggest you see it too. `www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ziyi4RkcNE`

Answer (score 6):

```
Name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
Phone = editTextMobile.getText().toString().trim();


JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(Name);
jsonArray.put(Email);
jsonArray.put(Phone);
final String mRequestBody = jsonArray.toString();

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, OTP_Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.v("LOG_VOLLEY", response);

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
            return null;
        }
    }

};
stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
VollySupport.getmInstance(RegisterActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
```

Comment: This is a long answer that should be accompanied by a detailed explanation. What does this do?

Comment: @Sanjeev Pal, Thanks a lot, Great answer and its working great for Http setEntity replacement

Answer (score 3):

> I created a function for a Volley Request. You just need to pass the arguments :

```
public void callvolly(final String username, final String password){
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://your_url.com/abc.php"; // <----enter your post url here
    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //This code is executed if the server responds, whether or not the response contains data.
            //The String 'response' contains the server's response.
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //This code is executed if there is an error.
        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MyData.put("username", username);             
            MyData.put("password", password);                
            return MyData;
        }
    };


    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Rest response",response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Rest response",error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("name","xyz");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("content-type","application/fesf");
            return params;
        }

    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```