# Unexpected response code 405 com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: android

I want to send form data to server. i m using volly library for that but this following code is showing bellow error.

> Unexpected response code 405 com.android.volley.ServerError

**My code is :**

```
public class Wow extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextLocation;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextWebsite;
    private Button buttonRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_sent_form);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextname);
        editTextLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextlocation);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextwebsite);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                suman();
            }
        });
    }

    void suman() {

        final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String location = editTextLocation.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String website = editTextWebsite.getText().toString().trim();

        try 
        {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = "http://myeducationhunt.com/schools/create";
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("name", name);

            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {


                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**logcat looks like this **

```
11-15 12:49:13.648 17579-19711/com.user.retrofit E/Volley: [254] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405 for http://myeducationhunt.com/schools/create
11-15 12:49:13.649 17579-17579/com.user.retrofit E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ServerError
```

Answer (score 2):

By Changing  Request GET FROM POST MY ERROR REMOVES .Thankyou for your valuable answer

Comment: changing POST to GET and changing url  from http://myeducationhunt.com/schools/create     to   http://myeducationhunt.com/schools shows   Unexpected response code 500,com.android.volley.ServerError

Comment: 500 cause internally better check what your are calling. its in server side not the client side

Comment: Changing POST to GET and changing url from myeducationhunt.com/schools/create to myeducationhunt.com/school

provide the data that are stored in database,but the form data are not submitted through emulator

Comment: try to look in this while waiting http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

Comment: does decoding in server side is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Try using GET method instead of POST
use `Request.Method.GET` instead of `Request.Method.POST`

Comment: instead of accessing data from server.i want to post form data to server.
please help

Comment: GET method can also be use instead of post to send data to server

Comment: when i press button register.then it is showing the list of database entity i.e JSon in emulator and logcat

Comment: try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body

Comment: there is no error.but the data are not posted in the above url?

Answer (score 0):

change your url from  `http://myeducationhunt.com/schools/create` to  `http://myeducationhunt.com/schools`.i think you a writing RESTful api on the server. when you use use POST method with `http://myeducationhunt.com/schools` url, it will automatically redirect to create function.

Comment: in your code, i see only name parameter that put in the JSON object.make sure the number of parameters are match between client and server.Also if you used POST method in RESTful api, there must be extra hidden field to prevent  CSRF Attack.

Comment: now i am having issue of com.android.volley.TimeoutError.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `getBodyContentType()` before `getBody()` it. Try adding this.

```
@Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }
```

Comment: adding  getBodyContentType() .doesnot help

Comment: it would be helpfull if you post server code as well

Comment: the issue is with server i.e of the extra hidden field to prevent CSRF Attack.
thank u all