# Volley: [213] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 415

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

Im using Restful Java to parse data json with POST method and Volley in android. When I try to insert data from Advanced REST Client, it insert data into db success, but in Android, when I insert data and see that it happen an exception as below:

My Restful (**UPDATED**):

```
@Path("/bookticket")
public class BookServiceCalled {
@POST 
@Path("/json")      
@Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")  //   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
public static void bookFromUser(@QueryParam("fullname") String fullname, 
                                 @QueryParam("birthday") Date birthday, 
                                 @QueryParam("address") String address) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;     
    try {
        // Config connect mydb          
        String query = "INSERT INTO order "
                + "(fullname, birthday, address) VALUES "
                + "(?,?,?) ";           
        statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);         
        statement.setString(1, fullname);
        statement.setDate(2, birthday);
        statement.setString(3, address);

        statement.executeUpdate();          

        System.out.println("Work !");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
            throw e;
    } 
    finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
        }
    }       
}
```

}

My activity class:

```
    private static final String URL_BOOK = "http://192.168.1.221:9999/bookticket_service/bookticket/json";

    EditText fullname, birthday, address;

    fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
    birthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthday);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    btnBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBook);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    btnBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_BOOK, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        
                }
            }){
               @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                   Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   parameter.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                   parameter.put("fullname", fullname.getText().toString());
                   parameter.put("birthday", birthday.getText().toString());
                   parameter.put("address", address.getText().toString());
                   return parameter;
               }
            };
            // volley saves the response in its cache and this behavior may cause some strange problem
            // request.setShouldCache(false);
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
```

Logcat:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Column 'fullname' cannot be null
```

How to fix the exception, thanks for the help

Comment: `StringRequest` by default produces `x-www-form-urlencoded` request ... putting `Content-Type` into parameter  generated by `getParams()` not changing it

Comment: I have tried but same error :(

Comment: mention `Content-type` in your web api as well

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari: can you guide me to set Content-Type in web api ?

Comment: @KhanhLuongVan in which language are you using your web api like php or .net

Comment: As you can see above, my web server im using: Java JDBC + restful

Comment: I have changed: @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") //   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, and then I recieved a new exception: Column 'fullname' cannot be null

Comment: @KhanhLuongVan, that Exception is pretty clear you have to insert record if your column is _NOT_ NULLABLE

Comment: Try using `getBody` instead of `getParams`, pls read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body/33578202#33578202, of course you can ignore `parseNetworkResponse` there. Another way, you can use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest`.

Comment: @BNK: Thank you, base on your answer I have fixed my problem :)