# Log request body with Volley in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using `StringRequest` to send HTTP POST request on my Android app. One of the POST requests returns `HTTP 400` when it is triggered via Volley. The API returns `HTTP 200` when it is triggered through rest clients(Postman, curl). I suspect there is something wrong in the request body sent through volley.

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
    {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("name", "Pomen Pogo");
            params.put("email", "pomen.pogo@staples.net");
            params.put("type", "Ninja");

            return params;  
    }
```

Is there any way to log the full request body that volley sends in the POST request? I've enabled `VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;`, It do logs the full response but It's is **NOT** logging the request body or URL.

Please help me to log the HTTP request details(url, request body etc.) in Volley.

Comment: Please put your entire network code and the code from the serve side. So that I can test it.

Comment: @BasuSingh Sorry, I can't disclose the API (Its a 3rd party API to which I need to POST the data). Can you please share how can I print the request body in Volley?

Comment: Post your Postman screenshot. Try using `getBody` instead of `getParams` also. You can refer my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body/33578202#33578202 (`parseNetworkResponse` can be ignored because it's for the 2nd requirement of that OP)

Answer (score -4):

Did you try the following?

```
Log.i(TAG, "Request body: " + new String(request.getBody()));
```