# Retrieve Json object in android using volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

Trying to get a value from my PHP API, on android, using volley... my API is working fine, returning the value I want, but on my android I can seem to save the value on a variable.

this is my PHP script

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$titu = $_POST['titulo'];
$id_use = $_POST['id_user'];
$difi = $_POST['dificuldade'];


$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$host= "localhost";
$dbname="check";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
$sql="insert into trilhos(titulo,id_user,dificuldade) 
values('".$titu."','".$id_use."','".$difi."');";


$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$id_trilho =mysqli_insert_id($con);

$result = array();
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$id_trilho));

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

on my android studio, I try to get the value like this, I send 3 values to insert into the database, and then I want to return the id of the row I inserted back to android. I have looked at many answers on StackOverflow but I just can't seem to understand and solve my problem.

```
public void insert(String titulo, String id_trilho, String dif) {
    url = "http://192.168.1.68/loginsignup/insertTrilho.php?titulo=" + titulo +"&id_user="+ id_trilho+ "&dificuldade=" + dif + "";
    Log.i("Http", "" + url);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(InserirTrilho.this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String id = jsonObject1.getString("id_trilho");
                Toast.makeText(InserirTrilho.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                SharedPreferences shared_id = getSharedPreferences("Mytrilho", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared_id.edit();
                editor.putString("id", id);


                editor.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(InserirTrilho.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(InserirTrilho.this, "Dados Errados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("HttpError","erro"+error);
        }

    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

keep getting a thrown exception, can someone help me out, thank you in advance

Comment: use this `jsonObject.getString("id_trilho");` instead of `jsonObject1.getString("id_trilho");`

Comment: This line of code `json_encode(array("result"=>$id_trilho));` will not give you the JSON structure you think you are trying to parse! Please update your question and provide an example of the JSON response your are getting back. I find it hard to believe that you are not getting an error.

Comment: Pavneet_Singh solved my problem, for some reason i cant edit my answer so that other people can see it correctly, but his answer solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is, url is a type of `Get` request but the method is in java request is of type `POST` so you need to send data as part of the request using as `Body` so

[**see how to send a POST request using volley with string body?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33578202/4936904)

---

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4936904/pavneet-singh) , Your response is `jsonobject` not array so use

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String id = jsonObject.optString("result");
```

instead of

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String id = jsonObject1.getString("id_trilho");
```

or to get what you want then use

```
$result = array();
$result["result"]= array();
array_push($result["result"],array("id_trilho"=>$id_trilho)); // assume $id_trilho =0
echo json_encode($result);
// output {"result":[{"id_trilho":0}]}
```

---

or simply use

```
$id_trilho = 0;
$result = array();
array_push($result,array("id_trilho"=>$id_trilho));
echo json_encode($result);
// output [{"id_trilho":0}]
// then use JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
// JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
// String id = jsonObject1.getString("id_trilho");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried everything you said, but i keep getting the same error

org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @Sapo121 there is an error in your sql query so rectify it's syntax as shown in the answer

Comment: everytime i test the script using postman i get a result and it inserts a new row on my DB, on my android i cant get a response

Comment: @Sapo121 use this `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String id = jsonObject.optString("result");`

Comment: {"result":[{"id_trilho":48}]}

Comment: @Sapo121 try the updated code,which is at the top for parsing

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

at com.example.helder.ipvc.estg.trilhosportugal.InserirTrilho$3.onResponse(InserirTrilho.java:106)

at com.example.helder.ipvc.estg.trilhosportugal.InserirTrilho$3.onResponse(InserirTrilho.java:98)

i dont know how to add the full log...

but those lines are 98 is StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

and 106 is   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: @Sapo121 use log to see the value of `response` and post it here because it clearly seems like you are receiving some other value

Comment: response=0 , this does not make any sense... sorry for bothering you, but i have stuck with this for some time, i simply need last_inserted_id from my query and pass it to my android so i can work with it.

Comment: make sure that your are hitting the right url, seems like you are using get url and using post, [How to send a POST request using volley with string body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body)

Comment: that could be the problem, i will try to fix it and get back to you, i used GET for some other stuff but i did not need to insert anything like now.

Comment: I got it to work, just changed the way i sent my data

@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String>stringMap = new HashMap<>();
                stringMap.put("titulo",titulo);
                stringMap.put("id_user",id_user);
                stringMap.put("dificuldade",dif);

                return stringMap;
            }
        };

and its working fine, thank you for your help

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding