# Not able to POST JSONObject in the body using Volley StringRequest

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to POST a JSONObject in the body of a volley StringRequest but unfortunately the server receives an empty body. The logs print the correct `mRequestBody` string as soon as the JSONObject is created and also in `getBody()`(see comments in the code). When I paste the printed `mRequestBody` in the Postman, it works perfectly. May I know what I'm doing wrong here and why it works from postman and not the app.

**Postman**

[image]

**Code:**

```
private void makeJSONObjectSend() {


    try {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

        jsonBody.put("FROMDATE", getFromSP("selectedFTimeValue"));
        jsonBody.put("TODATE", getToTime());
        if (jArraySelectedNo != null && jArraySelectedNo.length() > 0) {
            jsonBody.put("EMPNUMBER", jArraySelectedNo);
        } else {
            jsonBody.put("EMPNUMBER", new JSONArray());
        }
        if (jArraySelectedCounty != null && jArraySelectedCounty.length() > 0) {
            jsonBody.put("COUNTRYNAME", jArraySelectedCounty);
        } else {
            jsonBody.put("COUNTRYNAME", new JSONArray());
        }
        if (jArraySelectedState != null && jArraySelectedState.length() > 0) {
            jsonBody.put("STATENAME", jArraySelectedState);
        } else {
            jsonBody.put("STATENAME", new JSONArray());
        }

        String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString().replace("\\/", "/");

        Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY",mRequestBody); 
        //Here 'LOG_VOLLEY' prints correct JSONObject which works in postman
        //I/LOG_VOLLEY:  {"FROMDATE":"23/10/2021 13:52:00","TODATE":"24/10/2021 13:52:11","EMPNUMBER":["96940"],"COUNTRYNAME":["US"],"STATENAME":["AK"]}

        String URL = "http://myTestapi.com:xxx/folder/xxxx/GetPartEmpInfo";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY-22", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                    try {
                        String res = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                        Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", res);
                        
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } // returned data is not JSONObject?
                }
            }
        }) { 

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY2", mRequestBody);
                //Here 'LOG_VOLLEY2' prints correct JSONObject which works in postman
                //I/LOG_VOLLEY2:  {"FROMDATE":"23/10/2021 13:52:00","TODATE":"24/10/2021 13:52:11","EMPNUMBER":["96940"],"COUNTRYNAME":["US"],"STATENAME":["AK"]}
                return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                if (response != null) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.data);
                    Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY-2", responseString);
                }
                //return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }

            //This is for Headers
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + getFromSP("token"));
                return params;
            }

        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                240000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;

        if (requestQueue2 == null) {
            requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue2.add(stringRequest);
        } else {
            requestQueue2.add(stringRequest);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work. I was using this line in `params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` in the `getHeaders()` .

Changing that to `params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");` made it fix the issue.